# How to get rid of default contentDescription in android accessibility

Tags: android, android-view, accessibility

I have a gridview with 5*5 image views that is custom defined. After I turn on the accessibility and focus on a image view, i would like it read the name of this image instead of "row 1 column 1". So i use `imageView.setContentDescription(imageTitle);`, it's working but it reads like "imageTitle, row 1 column 1".

How do I get rid of the "row 1 column 1" (which I suppose is the default one)?

Any help is appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: any progress with it?

Answer (score 0):

You should setAccessibilityDelegate to gridview, CollectionInfo and CollectionItemInfo are set to null. Talkback will read the name of your image item.

```
gridView.setAccessibilityDelegate(new AccessibilityDelegate () {
    @Override
        @Override
        public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
            info.setCollectionInfo(null);
            info.setCollectionItemInfo(null);
        }
    }
});
```